# Name lookup error of enable_if'd inherited member functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I stumbled upon this weird name lookup issue, where a base class member function doesn't seem to participate in the overload selection at all, even though it is imported with a `using` statement. The member functions of the base and derived classes are both SFINAE'd with `enable_if_t`.

I was able to reproduce my issue with the following code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ueQ-kY

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class MyTag {};

struct Base
{
    template <typename RType>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<RType, int>::value> create(RType /*&&*/ ref)
    {
        std::cout << "Base::create(RType ref)" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    using Base::create;

    template <typename Tag>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Tag, MyTag>::value> create(Tag /*&&*/ tag)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::create(Tag tag)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;

    d.create(MyTag());
    d.create(0); // [x86-64 clang 7.0.0 #1] error: no matching member function for call to 'create'
}
```

While GCC compiles the above code without warnings, clang, icc, and MSVC aren't able to find a suitable overload for the call of `d.create(0);` and error the build. In fact, judging from the error messages, it seems like `Base::create` isn't even taking part in the overload resolution.

However, when one of the two member function takes its argument as a forwarding reference, the code compiles fine on all major compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gcc is wrong and should reject your example.

> ```
> using-declaration:
>     using using-declarator-list ;
> ```
>
> #### [`[namespace.udecl]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1)
>
> Each *using-declarator* in a *using-declaration* introduces a set of declarations into the declarative region in which the *using-declaration* appears. **The set of declarations introduced by the *using-declarator* is found by performing qualified name lookup** (`[basic.lookup.qual]`, `[class.member.lookup]`) for the name in the *using-declarator*, **excluding functions that are hidden as described below**.

The excluded functions being:

> #### [`[namespace.udecl]/15`](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#15)
>
> When a *using-declarator* brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting). Such hidden or overridden declarations are excluded from the set of declarations introduced by the *using-declarator*.

---

> However, when one of the two member function takes its argument as a universal reference, the code compiles fine on all major compilers.

When one of the function takes its argument as a (forwarding) reference, this template function doesn't qualify anymore as hidden since its *parameter-type-list* differs.

---

A bug report has been opened by OP, check it out:
[Bug 87478 - Hidden member function falsely takes part in qualified name lookup](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87478).

Comment: @oliv interesting. Do you have a link (I'm on my phone)?

Comment: Core issue 1980: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1980

Comment: @oliv I don't think it's related. This answer and this bug report are specific to using-declarators from a base class to a derived class of a template member function.

Comment: @YSC Maybe! Not applying this core issue here would make the language inconsistent. But this version of the standard include concepts, and apparently, they don't apply the same "function equivalence" for redeclarion and for using directive. I'am more surprised by this one. Hopefully they have overlooked it. Right now I am really disappointed, I thought the commitee intent was to increase the language consistency.